# How can I disable some Material UI css for ListItem

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material-UI ListItem component and I would like to get rid of the default background color. I've already tried using classes but my value gets overwritten by this:

How can I disable this default rule?

Comment: Pictures of code are not helpful.  Please publish all relevant code directly in your question.

Comment: Please show the code of what you tried.

Comment: There are many different ways of overriding styles in Material UI, see https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can globally override the style for any Material UI component.

Look for the point in your application where you call `createMuiTheme`, and add and `overrides` field like this.

```
 const theme = createMuiTheme({
     palette: {
         /* you should already have stuff here, keep it */
     },
     typography: {
         /* you should already have stuff here, keep it */
     },

     overrides: {
         MuiListItem: {
             root: {
                 backgroundColor: "red",
             },
         },
     },
 });
```

Comment: That's a really good answer if you want to affect the entire application. In some instances, I rather use css values with !important and that does the trick!